# Highlighting wrong Spelling in web browser control

Tags: c#, winforms

What I am trying to do is mark a dotted red Underline to each wrong spelling present in the web browser control which i have used in my winform Application.

Here is my Code snippet :-

```
    public static string CheckSpelling(string InnerHTML)
    {
        string Val = "";
        try
        {
            StringBuilder strBu = new StringBuilder();
            strBu.Append(InnerHTML);
            RemoveStyleAssigned(ref strBu);                               
            for (int i = 0; i < strBu.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToString(strBu[i]).ToLower() == "<")
                {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < strBu.Length; j++)
                    {                            
                        if (Convert.ToString(strBu[j]).ToLower() == ">")
                        {
                            i = j;
                            for (int k = j + 1; k < strBu.Length; k++)
                            {
                                if (Convert.ToString(strBu[k]).ToLower() != " ")
                                {
                                    i = k;
                                    CheckAndReplace(ref strBu, ref i);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (Convert.ToString(strBu[i]).ToLower() != " ")
                {
                    CheckAndReplace(ref strBu, ref i);                        
                }
            }
            Val = strBu.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        return Val;
    }
```

Here InnerHTML is the InnerHTML  of the web browser control obtained for entered data.
The Next Method is CheckandReplace

```
    private static void CheckAndReplace(ref StringBuilder strBu, ref int i)
    {            
        try
        {
            string Target = string.Empty;
            string NewString = "";                
            for (int j = i; j <= strBu.Length; j++)
            {                   
                if (j == strBu.Length || Convert.ToString(strBu[j]).ToLower() == " " || Convert.ToString(strBu[j]).ToLower() == "<" )
                {
                    string Wordtocheck = ReplaceXmlCharacters(Target);
                    if (!IsSpellingCorrect(Wordtocheck))
                    {
                        NewString = "<u style='text-decoration: none; border-bottom: 1px dotted #FF0000'>" + Target + "</u>";                           
                        strBu = strBu.Replace(Target, NewString, i, Target.Length);                            
                        i += NewString.Length - 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = j - 1;
                    }

                    break;
                }
                else
                    Target += strBu[j];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

**The Main Problem is that Everything works fine with the above code but whenever i get any special character or any space in the Target Value, the above code also highlight the same but I don't want to highlight that as done in MS Word.  Please Guide me through this or is their any other way out.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [check out Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx). Seems like it would help with what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: thanks for replying but Regex is not going to work out because if you look to the Inner HTML it converts any opening tag present in the data which will contain both alphabet and character..